# Heroku build directory is not a git repo, need something in HEAD

Tags: git, heroku

I have a repo that I am pushing to Heroku and building the app there.

It works fine, it builds in some `tmp/9d3ec2fc13fca868bfb7c417c28fd79f` directory.

Now, I am using using an npm package `git-revision-webpack-plugin` that adds the git tag as Version number.

It turns out that the directory is actually not a git repo, so the command fails. Ideally, I'd like to get this working. At worst, I can do without the tag and version, but be able to at least build.

I tried

`git init` to create a dummy git repo

and the npm package ran `git describe --always --tags`

That also didn't work because there's no head

`fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD`

Is there a way to fix so that I can assign something to HEAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have access to the git repo on Heroku even during build time. Running `git init` creates an empty repo, but you'd need to add and commit all files to get a SHA for git to describe. Even then, it would be different than the one your repo has on GitHub, locally, and what you push to Heroku.

I don't think the `git-revision-webpack-plugin` is going to work for you on Heroku unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. I am just trying to put some fake info in a .git folder to just get this plugin to work. I just find it bizarre that a tool (Heroku) that is built around git doesn't actually have stuff running in a git repo.

Comment: Heroku uses Git as a deployment tool, but it's not built around Git internally. The build is downloading the tarball of the repo (sans .git), and uploading a new tarball "slug" that's everything needed to boot up a new dyno with your app.

Comment: Yeah. I just created a new repo with `git init`, zipped the `.git` folder, put it in repo, and unzip it before building to get the revision plugin running.